# Three.js + Chrome 43: Error creating WebGL context

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I get an *"Error creating WebGL context"* error when running [this](http://codepen.io/fauxnoir/pen/vOmzJB) script in chrome 43 under Ubuntu Linux. It worked perfectly fine in chrome 42 ad in the stable release of Firefox. Here's the stack trace:

```
Error creating WebGL context.THREE.WebGLRenderer @ three.min.js:517(anonymous function) @ pen.js:24(anonymous function) @ pen.js:120
```

Note that I get this error in Chrome release 43 on the example script, but also on all the examples on threejs.org. The scripts prodcing this error use threejs r70 and r71

EDIT: I just noticed that this bug is specific to the chromium package on ubuntu linux, chrome works fine.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the same thing for Chromium 43.0.2357.81 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit), but Chrome 43 is fine. It seems to be a bug, [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=499363) is an issue in Chromium bug tracker about it. Chromium developer says:

> We have no control over which Chromium revision Ubuntu decides to pull into their distribution. It's entirely possible they pulled a broken revision. Sorry, but this is an issue you'll have to take up with Canonical.

[Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1466670) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1463598) are possible issues for Ubuntu Chromium distribution, but it seems to be not fixed yet.

I think for now the solution will be to downgrade to a working version and wait for a fix.

Comment: I've fixed this issue by switching to Google Chrome. If Canonical decides to pull broken builds for Chromium... Well... tough luck..