# THREE.js : Cannot read property 'getShaderPrecisionFormat' of null(…) + Error creating WebGL context

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js

I am using Google Chrome and in my project everything was fine a week ago.
But now I am coughthing errors from three.js file.

Strange, but it is fine working even in IE.
I tried to include different versions of three.js via [google cdn](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.min.js), [official site](https://threejs.org/), [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-js)... No results.

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955546/three-js-chrome-43-error-creating-webgl-context), but that one is enough old.
How to solve the problem?

Comment: http://news-lab-trends-experiment.appspot.com/ - the official example fails too http://prntscr.com/d8szpo